# NoSuchMethodError with ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic, nosuchmethoderror

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.activemq.thread.TaskRunnerFactory.setThreadClassLoader(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.getTaskRunnerFactory(BrokerService.java:1265)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createRegionBroker(BrokerService.java:2346)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.createBroker(BrokerService.java:2305)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.getBroker(BrokerService.java:1017)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.getAdminConnectionContext(BrokerService.java:2576)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startVirtualConsumerDestinations(BrokerService.java:2717)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startDestinations(BrokerService.java:2567)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.doStartBroker(BrokerService.java:726)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.startBroker(BrokerService.java:720)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:623)
    at com.bp.pnc.publisher.app.PncPublisherApplication.main(PncPublisherApplication.java:77)
```

The code I am using is

```
BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
connector.setUri(new URI("tcp://localhost:61616"));
broker.addConnector(connector);
broker.start();
```

The problem occurs at broker.start() method. I am using activemq 5.14.0. I am using Java 7. 
I looked at the documentation and exact line where this is happening.

**this.taskRunnerFactory.setThreadClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());**

Answer (score 2):

There are different reasons why this error can occur:

- You run your application with an older activemq.jar than the one you used for compiling your source
- Your application has more jars in its classpath and one of them contains classes of activemq as well (because it's using classes for itself). If that jar is loaded before your activemq.jar (i.e. it appears "in front" of the acitvemq.jar) the older version is in use.

If the latter, you can put the following code into your class (before the code you shown in your question) to see where the class is loaded from:

```
Class clazz = TaskRunnerFactory.class;
String name = clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
String loc = clazz.getClassLoader().getResource(name).toString();
System.out.println(loc);
```

Comment: I actually did what you wrote and it showing the location as file:/C:/Users/yahg3h/.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/activemq-client/5.9.1/activemq-client-5.9.1.jar!/org/apache/activemq/thread/TaskRunnerFactory.class                                                 So what does this mean? I have a parent pom which downloads 5.9.1 jar directly from our company repository. I think that is the reason it exists. How can I make sure that only 5.14.0 is available and not 5.9.1?

Comment: 5.9.1 < 5.14.0, so your application uses an older library than you used for compiling

Comment: How can I fix this?

Comment: Do I need to make changes to my pom? Since this is a child pom and there is other parent pom, how does that effect?

Comment: That's a new question and since I'm not that familiar with maven, I can't tell you for sure how to fix your pom.xml

Comment: So I am compiling with 5.14.0 and running with 5.9.0? What exactly is going wrong here? Can you explain concept from compilation to running and how it access these JAR's?

Comment: This is correct, check your POM file or child/parent POM, it must contain multiple entries of same dependency (may be different version) so at runtime, the method exist but it results in ambiguity hence it throws NoSuchMethodError , alternatively , in your maven dependencies, you can expand to check if that class and method exist in the JAR