# Stopping different JAR's being used for compilation and running application. How to fix maven dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, nosuchmethoderror

So the reason I am talking about this is because I had a Nosuchmethoderror. [NoSuchMethodError with ActiveMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133410/nosuchmethoderror-with-activemq).

What I am realized was my application was using different JAR's for compiling and running.

I have included activemq 5.14.0 in my pom but my pom is a child pom. It has a parent pom too.

So it is being compiled with 5.14.0 but is running with 5.9.1. I cant understand how to make sure it runs with 5.14.0 and not 5.9.1. 
Is it a problem because of the parent pom?

EDIT :
My dependency hierarchy
[image: dependency hierarchy]

In my properties tag in effective POM
[image: properties]

Comment: It depends what type of artifact it is. If it is a war and has version 5.9.1 jar ( and potentially 5.14.0 along with it) in it, then run maven dependency tree and see where is it coming from. If it does not have the jars then it might be that the application or servlet container has the 5.9.1 version it is classpath.

Comment: @tsolakp I am using embedded tomcat servlet container. I have looked up the effective pom and in the <properties> it is showing 5.9.1. I am deploying it as a JAR. Where do you think I can fix it for it to use only 5.14.1? I lookedup the parent effective pom and it is written 5.9.1 in the properties tag.

Comment: How can you deploy jar into tomcat. Are you sure it is jar and not a war?

Comment: @tsolakp I am using embedded tomcat. I am using springboot.