# How to stop Different maven dependencies being used for compilation and running an application

Tags: java, maven, nosuchmethoderror

My original problem of Nouschmethoderror. [NoSuchMethodError with ActiveMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133410/nosuchmethoderror-with-activemq). This problem led me here

I saw that my springboot java class was using Activemq 5.14.0 for compilation and it was using Activemq 5.9.1 for running.

I have a parent POM where activemq 5.9.1 was mentioned. I have a POM for my java class in which I mentioned 5.14.0 as the version used. So the 5.14.0 version was overwriting the 5.9.1 version for compilation.

But I dont know from where it is using 5.9.1 JAR when running the application.

I am attaching my effective POM for my java class and properties in effective POM of parent POM.
 [image: Effective POM of child]

[image: Parent POM properties Tag]

Comment: where are you using the `<activemq.version>` property as shown in the screenshot? Please share relevant pom.xml. Also the `mvn dependency:tree` can help you look at what is coming from where.

Comment: The solution is to fix the dependency conflict .... not to try to stop maven using the conflicted versions.

Comment: @nullpointer The relevant pom(parent pom) doesnt have a mention of activemq. This is the only place that I saw about activemq version in my parent pom.

Comment: How do you know that it is using 5.9.1 when running?